# The front of my 2001 Dakota apparently has been wrecked. I've found out that I have two different sized front brake pads

Tags: brakes, dodge, brake-calipers, dakota

Pads for drivers side are from a 1995 Dodge Dakota and the right passenger side are a 2001 what was changed out under my truck. I have had to purshase two different sets of brakes different sizes. Now the calipers need replacing. Do I have to buy a caliper for a 95 and for a 2001

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that both sides are identical, from suspension arms to hubs, brake discs, calipers and pads.

If not, then eccentric braking may be the cause of an accident and you may be liable if, and when, the insurance investigates.

You are responsible, in most places, for the safe condition of your vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one thing to say about this you need to get this fixed as soon as possible,you are responsible for keeping your car in a safe state.

To put it simple for you get the right parts for your car unless you do so your insurance is not valid and your insurance company will not cover any type of damage to you-your car-or any damage to property.

Get your car repaired by qualified people that uses the correct parts and send the bill to the person/company where you got the car.

Comment: Good luck with part 3 : think of "caveat emptor"...

Comment: well it needs to be repaired @SolarMike and it is kind of wrong to let the owner pay for the repair as he is not to blame for this,but i see your point :)

Comment: It may have been his local mechanic doing a cheap repair for him as asked... He may have owned the vehicle for 12 years or more....

Comment: @SolarMike my point is to get the car back in a safe condition,and to avoid serious problems for the owner of the car.

Comment: I understand liability my question is mechanical. The upper and lower control arms still have rivited ball joints. Does this mean the caliper mounting bracket and spindle were changed out on the wrecked side? BTW this was this way when I bought the truck.  I thought this was a mechanical site.

Comment: it doo look like atleast parts of the brake system are from the wrong modell of your car,it is important to have the same brake effect on both sides on the front or back of your car.i am sorry i focused on the safety part of your question in my answer.